# Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have no internet

Tags: 12.04, internet, dell, inspiron

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 onto an old Dell Inspiron 1521. I am unable to access the internet either by wireless or plugging the ethernet cable from the modem to the laptop. I'm thinking I need to install drivers but I'm not sure and don't know how to do that with Linux. First time using it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If Ethernet doesn't work, you are out of luck, but you would need to do a kernel update. Follow this guide to update kernel via ethernet: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

You are going to want to get the latest kernel. So, go to the bottom and download 3.13.6: linux-headers generic amd64, linux-headers generic all.deb, and linux image amd64. Then run cd /home/YOURUSERNAME/Downloads and then sudo dpkg -i *.deb. After that just reboot.

Comment: Ethernet isn't working for me, so am I unable to do this step? I also followed the links and couldn't find the latest kernel that you mentioned.